# How to create dynamics Link that shows up in Twitter feed?

Tags: twitter, branch.io

I've tried to create a dynamic links with `branch.io` to redirect to my mobile app but i encounter some issues : The tweet is not visible neither in general feed nor in notifications mention of the target user. However when i tweet with a normal url it's okay no problem.

Any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

That's very strange! What's the Branch link URL you're sharing on Twitter?